# Word VBA, Select whole document minus first page

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I know you can select the whole document like so

```
oWord.oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory
```

What would be the syntax to select the whole document minus the first page?

Context: Excel runs all the code and outputs ranges direct to word to build a report. Reports can be any number of pages and the amount of pages is not known. This code would run as the last piece so document would be built by this point.

Comment: Do you set any manual page breaks or section breaks?

Comment: A page in the system is defined as a range. e.g. range A1:K40 for page 1 and then a page break. for some pages it could be A1:K100 which takes up ~ two pages then a page break. so some pages do and some do not. I do not use any section breaks only page breaks

Comment: Are you talking about Word pages now or Excel pages??

Comment: in excel it does not have any page breaks etc ranges are entered into word and then after each range a page break is inserted into word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code selects everything from the second page onward:

```
Dim startRan As Range

Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
Set startRan = Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")

oDoc.Range(startRan.End, startRan.End).Select
Selection.EndKey unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
```

Comment: I get an error here oDoc.Range(startRan.End, startRan.End).Select on startRan.end says augment not optional? I commented that out and got errors on selection's but that was because I had to use oDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.... I also had a third error whilst that line was comment out on the GOTO line which says type mismatch. There are no bookmarks in the document? does that matter?

Comment: I was just doing a quickie here. For you of course the `Selection`s should be `oWord.Selection` and `oWord.oDoc.Range(startRan.End, startRan.End).Select`

Comment: Oh, and of course `Dim startRan As Word.Range` instead of just `Range`.