# VBA Search within page range in Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to make the Excel VBA search in a Word Document from page 5 onwards and once it finds the specific keyword it should target just the 1st encountered table and get some cells from the Word Table back to Excel as the code below will display. I am trying to introduce your Option1 in it but at the moment I can't. Any idea why?

```
 Option Explicit

    Sub Testt()

            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Dim Selection As Object
            Dim objWord As Word.Application
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim strValue As String
            Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
            Dim wdFileName As Variant
            Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
            Dim myTableRange As Word.Range ' formerly variable 'a'
            Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
        Dim pgNo As Long
        Dim FlName As String
        Dim SearchText As String
        Dim IopenedWord As Boolean


        Const wdMainTextStory As Integer = 1
    Const wdActiveEndPageNumber As Integer = 3
    Const wdStory As Integer = 6
    Const wdFindContinue As Integer = 1







            Set objWord = New Word.Application
            Set wdDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\Testt.docx")


            objWord.Visible = True


    With wdDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
                With .Find
                    .Forward = True
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .MatchWholeWord = True
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                    .Text = "Test"
                    .Execute


                    Do While objWord.Selection.Find.Execute = True
                '~~> Get the page number
                pgNo = objWord.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
                '~~> Check if the page number is >= 5
                If pgNo >= 5 Then
                    Debug.Print "Search text found in page " & pgNo
                End If
            Loop



                End With


                If .Find.Found Then


                    MsgBox "Found"
                Else
                    MsgBox "Not found"
                    Exit Sub


      End If

                Set myTableRange = .Duplicate.Next(unit:=wdTable)


        Dim rowNb As Long
        Dim ColNb As Long
        Dim x As Long
        Dim y As Long
        x = 8
        y = 1

        With myTableRange.Tables(1)
            For rowNb = 1 To 1 '
                For ColNb = 2 To 2


                    Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(rowNb, ColNb).Range.Text)

                    y = y + 1
                Next ColNb

                y = 1
                x = x + 1
            Next rowNb
        End With

        x = x + 2
     End With



    End Sub
```

Comment: Two ways I can think of **[1.]** Search the entire document and after `If .Find.Found Then` check if the page number of the selection (`Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)`) is `>=5` **[2.]** Select the word range from page 5 till the end of document and search that. For example see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697918/word-vba-select-whole-document-minus-first-page) on how to select the range of specific pages

Comment: Third way **[3.]** Open word document. Delete text from page 1 to page 4. Search text in the entire document. Close word document `without` saving.

Comment: Tried option 1 and 3, please see above in the code what I've tried

Comment: Here seems to be the issue With wdDoc.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory) as it is targeting everything and I tried to delete the 5th page, got type mismatch, and I selected WORD 16, from Excel in Tools>References would really appreciate if someone could help out a bit

Comment: Ok let me give you an example of option 1. Gimme 15-20 mins

Comment: Cool ! Sure, thank you ! Would really appreciate if you could do it on the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments above, I mentioned 3 ways to achieve what you want. I am sure there are other ways as well to skin a cat.

Here is an example (**Option 1**) on how to search for a text from page `5` onwards. I have commented the code. Still if you do not understand then feel free to leave a comment and if I can reply, I will.

```
Option Explicit

Const wdMainTextStory As Integer = 1
Const wdActiveEndPageNumber As Integer = 3
Const wdStory As Integer = 6
Const wdFindContinue As Integer = 1

Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim pgNo As Long
    Dim FlName As String
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim IopenedWord As Boolean

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        IopenedWord = True
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Sample File
    FlName = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.Docm"

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(FlName)

    '~~> Search Text. Change as applicable
    SearchText = "Siddharth"

    '~~> Move to the begining of the document
    oWordDoc.Bookmarks("\StartOfDoc").Select

    oWordApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

    With oWordApp.Selection.Find
        .Text = SearchText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        '~~> Loop and find the search text
        Do While oWordApp.Selection.Find.Execute = True
            '~~> Get the page number
            pgNo = oWordApp.Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
            '~~> Check if the page number is >= 5
            If pgNo >= 5 Then
                Debug.Print "Search text found in page " & pgNo
            End If
        Loop
    End With

    oWordDoc.Close (False)

    If IopenedWord = True Then oWordApp.Quit
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

And if I change

```
If pgNo >= 5 Then
    Debug.Print "Search text found in page " & pgNo
End If
```

to

```
Debug.Print "Search text found in page " & pgNo
```

Then I get this

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's great, now the problem is that I  have to readjust it a bit, please have a look above at the edited code that I have provided. The Excel VBA has to search for a keyword in the Word Document starting from page  5 onwards until the end of the Word Document. Once the specific keyword is found, it should target the 1st encountered table and copy some cells from it back to Excel.

Comment: `Once the specific keyword is found, it should target the 1st encountered table and copy some cells from it back to Excel.` This warrants a new question. Feel free to ask a new question and post the link here.

Comment: Cheers, really much appreciated ! Below is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991687/search-in-word-doc-from-page-5-onwards-find-specific-word-and-copy-from-the-1st